# finding entities with duplicate value on different relations

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i have a dynamic form builder , it has 3 tables

```
fields : id , title , type (int,string,image ,.... )

user_forms :  id , user_id , ... 

user_form_fields : id, field_id , user_form_id , value
```

lets say i have 2 fields called  `product model` and `serial number`

```
fields : id , title
          1   PRODUCT MODEL
          2   SERIAL NUMBER
```

wehn user is registering form and sends modelX with serial number of 666
i store them in the user_form_fields table like this

```
user_form_fields : field_id , user_form_id , value 
                      1            1         modelX
                      2            1         666
```

i've noticed due to some front error , we've been receiving the same value for both fields ... like we've stored `666` value for both serial and model fields , the good news is we can correct this manually and find the model based on serial number .... but i need to find these forms with wrong field values first

right now i have to read all the forms from db and check the relation for duplicate values on on the code

```
    $userForms = \App\Models\UserForm::with('UserFormFields')
    ->get();
    
    foreach ($userForms as $k=>$userForm)
    {
        $modelNumber  = $userForm->UserFormFields->firstWhere('field_id' , 1 );
        $serialNumber = $userForm->UserFormFields->firstWhere('field_id' , 2 ) ;

        if(  $modelNumber->value == $serialNumber ->value)
        {
           /// corect data
        }

    }
```

since i have ~2 million records in db i keep running out of ram on the loop ... i was wondering if there is a way to this check in the database level and only get forms with duplicate values in 2 relation , so i can create a queue to handle them one by one

Comment: wouldnt be easier to group by the value and filter those having count > 1 ?

Comment: Upload the file and import it with phpmyadmin or by comand

Comment: @N69S  i was hoping a cleaner way but not a bad idea

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a self-join on the user_form_fields table to find forms with duplicate values for model and serial number.

**Raw SQL**

```
SELECT uff1.user_form_id
FROM user_form_fields uff1
JOIN user_form_fields uff2 ON uff1.user_form_id = uff2.user_form_id
WHERE uff1.field_id = 1 -- Product Model field_id
AND uff2.field_id = 2 -- Serial Number field_id
AND uff1.value = uff2.value;
```

**Using Laravel:**

```
$duplicateForms = DB::select("
    SELECT uff1.user_form_id
    FROM user_form_fields uff1
    JOIN user_form_fields uff2 ON uff1.user_form_id = uff2.user_form_id
    WHERE uff1.field_id = 1
    AND uff2.field_id = 2
    AND uff1.value = uff2.value
");

// Loop through the duplicateForms and process them as needed
foreach ($duplicateForms as $form) {
    $userForm = \App\Models\UserForm::with('UserFormFields')->find($form->user_form_id);
    // Process the correction for the form
    // ...
}
```